# bubble sort outer loop in python

Tags: python, bubble-sort

The canonical python implementation of bubble sort looks like this:

```
array = [5,2,7,8,1,6,3]
n = len(array)

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n-i-1): 
        if array[j] > array[j+1]:
            array[j],array[j+1] = array[j+1], array[j]
```

Now, my understanding is the total number of passes of the outer loop should be n-1 where n is the array size. However, in the python code above, range produces the sequence 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 and iterates through the loop 7 times? What am I missing here?

Comment: `array[i] > array[j]`

Comment: The outer loop iteration count is the length of the array, not n-1.  `range(n)` will be `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`.  It stops at `n-1`, but the count is `n`.  You COULD use `range(n-1)`, since the inner loop won't run when `i == n-1`.